# Is Oracle JDK link broken for Linux?

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, java, wget

I was running a tutorial on YouTube for installing Oracle JDK on Linux. My script seems to have worked but I can no longer run

```
wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

What new methodology or script can I use to install Oracle JSK on Linux?

Comment: I don't think their stock price is related to fixing your question.

Comment: What makes you think that's the correct url?

Comment: @KirkWoll 1)The same methodology I used in all my scripts by right clicking the browser link and 'cop link location' and https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2365607

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Oracle JDK link is broken, you have to click through the website and accept the terms.

Second link on Google, the first being this question (Wow, Googlebot is *fast*) is an [Oracle discussion thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2365607):

> Hi,
>
> Unfortunately we have to require license acceptance prior to download.
>   This can be implemented in one of two ways. Either we require
>   registration and log in prior to download, and as part of registering
>   you agree to reading and complying with licenses. Or we use a
>   click-through on download which avoids the need to register and log
>   in. We have chosen the latter for Java downloads as the least
>   intrusive method. We found out some time ago that scripts were being
>   used to circumvent click-through (in violation of site policies, and
>   frankly also of common sense) and have plugged this hole.
>
> We understand that this makes command line updates from our main
>   website for Linux users impossible and are actively looking for other
>   ways to enable this use case.
>
> Oracle JDK is based on OpenJDK (with a few added components like a
>   closed-source font rasterizer that we license from a third party) and
>   the latter is available as part of most Linux distributions, so it is
>   a good option unless you specifically need the Oracle certified
>   binaries.
>
> Regards,
>
> Henrik Ståhl Sr. Director, Product Management Java Platform Group
>   Oracle

Comment: @chaosite So OpenJDK is the future...

Comment: @chaosite so why is my previous script broken? I already used the script previously and therefore the JDK without a license and am not required to have a license for that JDK on the other system I have. In fact can I distribute that version seeing as Oracle is saying that I didn't need a license previously?

Comment: @thejartender: I'm not a lawyer, I'm not *your* lawyer, and in no way  is this legal advice, but the license does state that by using the software you are bound by the license. Since you can't legally use the JDK *without* a license, you probably want to have one.

Comment: @chaosite what license? The script I used for the version of Java I have never asked me to sign/agree to a thing. I am gonna talk to the Foss community about this and the legal implications... Oracle left a hole in their systems and there are versions of Java floating around that didn't need an agreement. I doubt any law bans you from using wget on something that is open.

Comment: @thejartender if you're not authorized to download something, then it's unauthorized access. If you didn't agree to the license, you weren't authorized. There *are* laws against it. Oracle probably doesn't care enough to sue you, I mean it's a free download anyway, but licenses are between people, not computers, and don't think for one second that just because a computer lets you access something you automatically get a license to distribute it, or even access it. But really, don't ask me, ask a lawyer!

Comment: @Chaosite http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtWGY9x8P9Y

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is pretty obvious if you look at what you get back:

> In order to download products from Oracle Technology Network you must
>   agree to the OTN license terms.
>   Be sure that...
>   - Your browser has "cookies" and JavaScript enabled.
>   - You clicked on "Accept License" for the product you wish to download.
>   - You attempt the download within 30 minutes of accepting the license.

When you do it from a browser you have to select the radiobutton "Accept License Agreement" and that's when the cookie is set. You should be able to download it using links or lynx.

Comment: @FredrikWhat on earth would make you assume I saw that message in my terminal?

Comment: @thejartender Well, wget will tell you that it downloaded "download-fail-1505220.html" (or something similar). If could be just me but I would type "less <file>" if I saw it :-)

Comment: can't install the agreed version either...http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtWGY9x8P9Yet/

Comment: Seriously, you need to fresh up your linux/unix knowledge... You were in your home directory when you unpacked the tar ball. The unpacked tarball shouldn't be in the download directory but in your home directory after that. There is NOTHING wrong with that tar ball. If you can't handle tar from the command line, klick the tar file in the Folder window you have on the display and use whatever tool your linux opens it with,

Answer (score 0):

After agreeing and downloading the JDK, run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Author: Yucca Nel http://thejarbar.org
#Will restart system
#Modify these variables as needed...
tempWork=/tmp/work
locBin=/usr/local/bin
javaUsrLib=/usr/lib/jvm
downloadDir=~/Downloads

sudo mkdir -p $javaUsrLib
mkdir -p $tempWork
cd $tempWork

#Extract the download
tar -zxvf $downloadDir/*linux*
#Move it to where it can be found...

sudo mv -f $tempWork/jdk* $javaUsrLib/

sudo ln -f -s $javaUsrLib/jdk1/bin/* /usr/bin/

#Update this line to reflect versions of JDK...
export JAVA_HOME="$javaUsrLib/jdk1.7.0_03"
#Extract the download
tar -zxvf $tempWork/*

#Move it to where it can be found...

sudo mv -f $tempWork/jdk1* $javaUsrLib/

sudo ln -f -s $javaUsrLib/jdk1*/bin/* /usr/bin/
sudo rm -rf $tempWork
#Update this line to reflect newer versions of JDK...
export JAVA_HOME="$javaUsrLib/jdk1.7.0_02"

if ! grep "JAVA_HOME=$javaUsrLib/jdk1.7.0_02" /etc/environment
then
    echo "JAVA_HOME=$javaUsrLib/jdk1.7.0_02"| sudo tee -a /etc/environment
fi


exit 0
```